# STM32F103 random reboots

Tags: pcb, stm32, reset, ground-loop

we have made a 2 layer board for a STM32f103, and apparently it works fine but we get a random resets now and then. When that occurs there is a 1 in the Bit 27 PORRSTF: POR/PDR reset flag and Bit 26 PINRSTF: PIN reset flag of the Control/status register (RCC_CSR). I think it might be some kind of noise on that trace? This is a picture of that portion of the PCB, with the RESET trace highlighted.
Any ideas of what could be the error?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show a schematic of the reset circuit, too.  What is the nature of the equipment, and what is connected to it?  Is the reset net on that header?  Is it exposed to people's fingers?

Comment: Could be caused by noise on the ground at the SWD connector too (if there are any high current devices/loads elsewhere on the board).  With board layouts like this, noise on either ground or VCC near the chip are also worth looking into.  Life is easier/better with 4 layer boards...

Comment: Is RESET active low or high? Does it have a pull-up/down resistor and bypass cap right at the MCU pin? If not local noise can cause false resets.

Comment: What is the purpose of this board?

Comment: Is Q2 a crystal, and is the highlighted blue trace running parallel under red trace N$1 to the STM? If a 2-sided PCB, that wouldn't couple much, but if it were 4-layer, the layers could be much closer. Try adding a little more pull-up/down to that line.

Comment: Schematic added. The PCB is a HMI LCD controller, it communicates to another microcontroller electrically isolated in the same PCB that receives data from digital sensors and is connected to a stepper motor driver. The PCB is enclosed in a metal case. @ChrisStratton

Comment: The reset is pulled high via 10k resistor, but does not have a bypass cap in the board, I soldered one on the SWD connector and it behaves as before @Sparky256

Comment: @rdtsc Yes, the highlighted blue trace is running parallel under red trace N$1 to the STM. I have reduced the pull up value of the resistor and there is no resets for now, I will leave it for a few hours. Please, could you explain why changing this value affects the resets?

Comment: I'd place a small (like 10 to 100 nF) capacitor to ground on the NRST line as close as possible to the pin not at the SWD connector, position matters a lot for proper decoupling.

Comment: Stepper driver, huh... as in large current pulses?  Electrically "isolated" how exactly?

Comment: Have you probed the supplies and reset pin with an oscilloscope to see if there are any power outages or resets? Mind that the nRST pin is a bidirectional IO pin, so the MCU will keep it low for some time by itself when a reset happens. Typically, the nRST pin would not have an external pull-up resistor, just for info. The suggested circuit is to have just a capacitor on nRST pin.